# integrated camera not detected/working on Acer Nitro 5 AN515-58

Tags: ubuntu, camera, acer

The integrated camera is not detected/working.
Cheese says `No device found`.
Guvcview says

```
Guvcview error
no video device (/dev/video0) found
```

I have dual boot with Windows 10 and the camera works there.

From what I saw in other threads, the following information might be useful. Let me know if you need anything else.

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Linux Lite 6.0
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

uname -r

```
5.19.3-051903-generic
```

lsusb

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
**Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0408:4035 Quanta Computer, Inc. ACER HD User Facing**
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsusb -d 0408:4035 -v https://pastebin.com/GQVWC6i3

sudo lshw | grep -i "facing" -B 2 -A 8

```
      *-usb:1 UNCLAIMED
           description: Video
           product: ACER HD User Facing
           vendor: Quanta
           physical id: 6
           bus info: usb@3:6
           version: 0.04
           serial: 01.00.00
           capabilities: usb-2.01
           configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
      *-usb:2
```

lsmod | grep video

```
uvcvideo              110592  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       81920  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
videodev              270336  5 v4l2_async,videobuf2_v4l2,ov13858,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     65536  6 v4l2_async,videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,ov13858,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
video                  61440  2 acer_wmi,i915
```

ls /dev/video*

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

launching cheese in the terminal

```
Gtk-Message: 09:31:49.172: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2220: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.
** Message: 09:31:49.359: cheese-application.vala:222: Error during camera setup: No device found


(cheese:38985): cheese-CRITICAL **: 09:31:49.364: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:38985): GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:31:49.364: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:38985): GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:31:49.364: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:38985): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:31:49.364: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:38985): GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:31:49.364: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:38985): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 09:31:49.364: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:38985): GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:31:49.364: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:38985): CRITICAL **: 09:31:49.364: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

v4l2-ctl --list-devices

```
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.
```

sudo dmesg | grep -i "uvcvideo"

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.3-051903-generic root=UUID=50e8040d-7168-413e-9142-0ceee2ab6347 ro uvcvideo.quirks=0x100
[    0.036909] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.3-051903-generic root=UUID=50e8040d-7168-413e-9142-0ceee2ab6347 ro uvcvideo.quirks=0x100
[    4.629731] uvcvideo 3-6:1.1: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : 26 (exp. 48).
[    4.630448] uvcvideo 3-6:1.1: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
[    4.631364] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the driver will be updated shortly to support this Quanta Camera
0408:4035

If you want to test the new eta uvcdriver, please apply.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2000947

Kindly report on launchpad if your problem is fixed.

BR